# how to add multiple user with multiple times

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make 1 user and be able to add multiple images for this user.  I'm thinking about adding content_group for using GROUP UP.  Is this the correct database structure?

USER

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    TESTNAME      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

CONTENT

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         id .        |      user_id     |      picture     | content_group
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |       1 .jpg     | xxxxxx
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          1       |       2 .jpg     | yyyyyy
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: Sure, that works. But I would name 'id' columns literal as what id they are, so theres very little guesswork overall when looking at queries and tables. "Is ID for this, or ID for that, or ID is ID what now?" Meaning, if its "UserID" in one table, it should be "UserID" in the other table... with "ImageID" for the other (so you can like JOIN USING(UserID)). BUT then again, thats all "OPINION", so YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks reasonably well. If you are adding 'content groups', you should continue the same pattern though.

I think I would expect your data model to look a little bit more like this. I renamed some fields. This is super subjective, but this is how I'd probably expect the fields to be called.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE content (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   image_filename VARCHAR(50),
   category_id INT UNSIGNED
);

CREATE TABLE content_category (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,      
   name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

You might want to add some foreign keys, but it's ultimately optional. Not everyone uses them in MySQL.

The above data-model assumes that categories are shared. If categories belong to specific users, then that table should also get a `user_id` field.

Furthermore, if categories are per-user and a category is required to exist for every item in `content`, it means that the `user_id` field is not needed in the `content` table, because you can find it through the categories table.

So here's an alternative where categories are per-user and required:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE content (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
   image_filename VARCHAR(50),
   category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE content_category (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
   name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Comment: thank you could you give me some simple  select * from query  pls.

Comment: some things like this ? `SELECT * FROM USER  
LEFT JOIN content_category ON user.id = content_category.user_id
LEFT JOIN content ON content_category.id = content.category_id`

Comment: I can write you a sample query under 2 conditions: 1. You tell me exactly what your query should return (a list of content for a user? a list of categories for user?) and 2. You show me what you tried.